# Beers on the wall in C loop issue

Tags: c, for-loop

I have made the program run fine, however the output is not exactly as I want it to be. It out puts "99 bottles of beer on the wall, 99 bottles of beer, take one down pass it around, 99 bottles of beer on the wall" and goes down accordingly. However, I want the last number value to be 98, not 99. And so on.

When I use numBeers--, it works but has this issue. When I use numBeers - 1, it just keeps looping 99, to 98, to 99, to 98, if that's understandable.

How can I make it so it subtracts one from the last number, and continues to go down to 0?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  int numBeers;

  for (numBeers = 10; numBeers >= 0; numBeers = numBeers) {
    printf("%d bottles of beer on the wall, %d bottles of beer\n", numBeers);
    printf("Take one down, pass it around, %d bottles of beer on the wall.\n\n",
        numBeers - 1);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is that really what it prints? Because your first `printf` statement is waiting for 2 integer values, and you're only giving it one.

Comment: `numBeers = numBeers`...what do you think this does?

Comment: Hint: `numBeers--` and `--numBeers` are 2 different things. Also, `numBeers = numBeers` is just useless, does nothing. May even be removed by the compiler. You'll also get an issue on your last iteration, where numBeers equals 0, because the last line after decrementation will display -1 beers.

Comment: @AntonH Thank you friend  ! Btw, in reference to your first statement, i have the numBeer used twice for the placeholder now.

Comment: The proper thing to do is put `numBeers -= 1` (or `--numBeers`) in the `for` statement, and `numBeers - 1` in the `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

The loop variable must be updated in this case. Since this loop assigns the same value to itself, it may lead to infinite loop.
So try doing

for (numBeers = 99; numBeers >= 1; numBeers = numBeers - 1)

Comment: That works, but experienced C programmers would use `numBeers--` (or possibly `--numBeers`).